# Как вывести массив в json

Tags: java, android

Я создал новый класс, что бы подключится к серверу(Где находится Json) с помощью AsyncTask, мне надо создать кнопку, которые при нажатию переходит на ссылку.
Пытался вывести масив, но не помогло.

Вот код **MainActiviy.java**

```
package my.home.page;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;

import org.json.JSONException;

import my.home.page.classss.ParseTask;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static String LOG_TAG = "my_log";
    String Links, names;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        String str = null;
        try {
            str = this.getJSON();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(str);

    }


    private String getJSON() throws JSONException {
        ParseTask pt = new ParseTask();
        pt.execute();


        return null;
    }
}
```

Вот так выглядит Json на сервере

```
[{"id":1,"link":"www.vk.com","name":"VK"},
 {"id":1,"link":"www.google.com","name":"google"},
 {"id":1,"link":"www.ya.ru","name":"Yandex"}]
```

Comment: [гляньте здесь](https://www.learn2crack.com/2013/10/android-asynctask-json-parsing-example.html)

Answer (score 3):

Для начала посмотрите на свой код.

- В активити вы пытаетесь получить строку с помощью метода getJSON
- Смотрим что возвращает метод getJSON: он возвращает null

Логично что вы ничего не видите в выводе

А вообще Вам следует лучше изучить андроид и AsyncTask в частности:

- В android в теле activity вы не можете напрямую обращаться к сети
- Основной поток отвечает за UI и вы не можете его тормозить тяжелыми процессами, коим является обращение к сети
- Для тяжелых процессов и обращения к сети в частости можно использовать AsyncTask - задания, которые выполняются в отдельном потоке
- Вывод в лог вы можете сделать и непосредственно в методе doInBackground после получения данных из сети
- Для доступа к UI в AsyncTask можно переопределить метод onPostExecute который выполняется после выполнения задания и используется для обновления интерфейса
- Метод onPostExecute получает данные, которые вы должны были получить в методе doInBackground
- Для этого вы должны вернуть эти данные с использованием конструкции return в методе doInBackground

**Подробнее:**

- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html
- http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/149-urok-86-asynctask-znakomstvo-neslozhnyj-primer.html
- http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/150-urok-87-asynctask-parametry-promezhutochnye-rezultaty.html
- http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/asynctask.php

Comment: ну у меня AsyncTask в отдельном потоке\

Comment: и как я понял, onPostExecute напо писать в одном потока с doInBackground?

Comment: Вам не нужно самому вызывать метод onPostExecute.

Comment: Вам нужно его только переопределить.

Comment: Он вызывается в методе execute  после вызова метода doInBackground

Answer (score 1):

Лучше используйте библиотеку **Retrofit**. Вот [ссылка](http://java-help.ru/retrofit-2-review/) на пример.

Comment: ретрофит это хорошо!Но сперва нужны знания а потом доп библиотеки